# Tortoise SVN shelve from command line

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

I have tortoise SVN installed

```
>svn --version
svn, version 1.14.2 (r1899510)
```

I can shelve files using the panel menu

[image]

But I want to automate the process, but it doesn't seem to have the shelve command line option

```
>svn shelve
Unknown subcommand: 'shelve'
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

How can I shelve from the command line? Can't do with the patch option because I work with binary files